# alignparentbottom for a relativelayout inside scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview

I'm trying to put some content(in this case the LL with id 'bottomcontent') at the bottom of the screen and when user starts scrolling I like to show more content at the bottom of it. Any ideas how to do this? I have the following code, but there is no scrolling since the LL below 'bottomcontent' gets height = 0

```
Here is the code:
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MyActivity"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <!-- I expect this to occupy one full screen, since its child is asking for align parent bottom = true-->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:id="@+id/top">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/bottomcontent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/hello_world"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <!-- When user scrolls, I expect this linear layout to be seen. But I get its height to be zero, so no scrolling-->
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
                >


                <TextView
                    android:text="hello_world hello_world hello_world hello_world hello_world hello_world hello_world "
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 4):

What I got from your question is that you want a scrollview but you aloways want a LL to show at bottom of the screen. Even when user scrolls, the LL should show at the bottom, right? You may try following layout.

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        <RelativeLayout>
            <!--...everything you want to show in scrollview -->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        <!--...your layout which you want to always show at bottom.-->
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This will have LL stagnant at bottom and the rest will scroll.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but thats not exactly it. There is no stagnant part. The LL should be shown only when user scrolls up. LL is below the screen and will be available upon scrolling

Comment: So is it at the end of ScrollView and is only shown to user when he scrolls up?

Comment: LL is part of scrollview, but the last view of it. If that is what you meant by end of scrollview, yes..

Comment: So you have `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in your RL which is inside the ScrollView. What happens if you do wrap content to it? Since your RL is taking all the height, ofcourse it will hide the LL. So either use weights for both the laoyouts or do wrap content to both...

Comment: have you solved your issue? I have the same, and can't do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916384/how-to-align-textview-recyclerview-at-screen-bottom-within-scrollview