# How to align TextView + RecyclerView at screen bottom within ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have the next structure of XML file in my Fragment. I have an issue with RelativeLayout 3 (id=referralsContainer). It consist of textView (id=inviteText) + RecyclerView (id=rv_referrals). I need to show textView at the bottom of screen with any resolution. And after that textView must be RecyclerView with elements (when user will scroll down). I tried to do something like this in method, when all elements of recyclerview loaded, but recyclerview is replaced in different positions by Y axe from time to time, I can't understand how to correctly place that textview at the bottom of the scrren. And also ScrollView cuts several items of recyclerView. Does anybody can help with this? All positions in debugger looks right. Code+xml is below image. Thanks.

[image]

```
this.dataSourceListForAdapter.addAll(incomeListOfItemsFromServer);
recyclerView.setY(scrollView.getBottom() - textView.getHeight());
recyclerView.setY(coordinatorView.getBottom() - textView.getHeight());
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/invite_friends_swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/invite_friends_content_part"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:visibility="visible">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/invite_friends_container"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="190dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:background="@color/re_black_light_new">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/invite_friends_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_above="@+id/invite_friends_button_container"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:paddingEnd="40dp"
                            android:paddingStart="40dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            tools:text="@string/friends_invite_message" />

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/invite_friends_button_container"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="40dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/combined_shape_white" />

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                android:background="@color/white" />

                            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                                android:id="@+id/invite_friends_button_invite"
                                android:layout_width="147dp"
                                android:layout_height="40dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                                card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
                                card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
                                card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                                card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/invite_friends_button_invite_text"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/yellow_button_selector"
                                    android:clickable="true"
                                    android:focusable="true"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="@string/friends_invite"
                                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                                    android:textColor="@color/re_black_light_new"
                                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/copy_choice_label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/invite_friends_container"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:text="@string/copy_link_text"
                        android:textColor="@color/re_gray_new" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/invite_friends_referal_link_button"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/copy_choice_label"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_gray">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/invite_friends_referal_link_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:focusable="true"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="7dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/re_black_light"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/invite_friends_full_info_container"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/invite_friends_referal_link_button"
                        android:layout_marginTop="32dp">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/invite_friends_container_central"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/invite_friends_text_friends"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                                android:text="@string/friends_invite_friends"
                                android:textColor="@color/re_black_light_new"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/invite_friends_friends_count"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/invite_friends_text_friends"
                                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                                android:textColor="@color/re_black_light_new"
                                android:textSize="24sp"
                                tools:text="4" />

                            <View
                                android:id="@+id/invite_friends_divider_horizontal"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="1dp"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/invite_friends_friends_count"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/dash_horizontal_gray"
                                android:layerType="software" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/invite_friends_text_orders"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/invite_friends_divider_horizontal"
                                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                                android:text="@string/friends_invite_orders"
                                android:textColor="@color/re_black_light_new"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/invite_friends_orders_count"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/invite_friends_text_orders"
                                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                                android:textColor="@color/re_black_light_new"
                                android:textSize="24sp"
                                tools:text="32" />

                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/invite_friends_container_central"
                            android:layout_width="1dp"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/dotted_line"
                            android:layerType="software" />

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/invite_friends_container_central">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/invite_friends_income_text"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                                android:text="@string/friends_invite_income"
                                android:textColor="@color/re_black_light_new"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/invite_friends_income_container"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/invite_friends_income_text"
                                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/invite_friends_income_count"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                                    android:lines="1"
                                    android:maxLines="1"
                                    android:textColor="@color/re_black_light_new"
                                    android:textSize="24sp"
                                    tools:text="1488.77" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/invite_friends_income_currency"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                                    android:lines="1"
                                    android:maxLines="1"
                                    android:textColor="@color/re_black_light_new"
                                    android:textSize="12sp"
                                    tools:text="руб." />

                            </LinearLayout>

                            <View
                                android:id="@+id/invite_friends_divider_horizontal_2"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="1dp"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/invite_friends_income_container"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/dash_horizontal_gray"
                                android:layerType="software" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/invite_friends_text_income_pending"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/invite_friends_divider_horizontal_2"
                                android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                                android:text="@string/friends_invite_income_pending"
                                android:textColor="@color/re_black_light"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/invite_friends_text_income_pending_container"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/invite_friends_text_income_pending"
                                android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/invite_friends_text_income_pending_count"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                                    android:textColor="@color/re_gray_new"
                                    android:textSize="24sp"
                                    tools:text="0" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/invite_friends_text_income_pending_count_currency"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                                    android:lines="1"
                                    android:maxLines="1"
                                    android:textColor="@color/re_gray_new"
                                    android:textSize="12sp"
                                    tools:text="руб."/>

                            </LinearLayout>

                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/referralsContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/invite_friends_content_part"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/inviteText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                        android:text="Вы уже пригласили:"
                        android:textColor="@color/re_black_light_new"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/scrollMore"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/inviteText"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_scroll_more" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/rv_referrals"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/scrollMore"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/invite_friends_error_part"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/error_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/lost_connection_holder" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/error_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/error_image"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/no_connection_message"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_tr_38"
                    android:textSize="19sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: you can use bottom sheet for that purpose ...i think that would be a better material design...

Answer (score 1):

ScrollView is not purposed for sub-child layouts aligned to the bottom of screen as its direct child doesn't know where the bottom is. From your question is not clear how do you need (want) to scroll bottom part.

If it is ok to scroll by dragging bottom part (RelativeLayout 3) it is better to use [BottomSheetBehaviour](https://medium.com/@nullthemall/new-bottomsheet-caab21aff19b) in Coordinatorlayout for this layout.

If not then just put RelativeLayout 3 under (below) SwipeRefreshLayout and handle ScrollView scrollChanged events to animate scrolling of bottom layout if you need or just show/hide this bottom layout.

Don't forget that on small resolutions layout aligned to the bottom will cover the content of ScrollView and user won't be able to scroll top layout.